# How to disable GPU rendering on Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 8"

Tags: root-access, overclocking, gpu

You're reading it right, I'm trying to do the oposite as others. **I want to use CPU for rendering.**
The reason is simple. My tablet is freezing very frequently. I have no warranty, so I'm trying to solve problem by lowering performance of device.
I isolated a problem and I'm sure freezing is caused by GPU. It freezes on gfx intese moments(few seconds of video playback), or on overlay (Eg. opening search dialog in google play causes almost instant freeze).
So the question stands:
**How can I disable GPU rendering on my device**(I have terminal with root access if it helps)?
What I already tried:
1. Underclocking CPU has no effect on freezing. I tried powersave mode with 200MHz, with no impact on problem.
2. Underclocking GPU has also no effect on freezing.

Comment: did you check out developer options?

Comment: IMO, it's unlikely the issue is GPU rendering. The search dialog is hardly a graphic intensive view, and neither is playing a simple video. Can you play any graphic intensive games?

Comment: I didn't check developer options, but I will now, thanks for a tip.
I wrote it freezes on gfx intensive situations or overlay. Game CSR racing freezes after 3-5s when in 3D. Youtube app is the same as google play, hitting search button causes freeze (I presume suggestion window overlay).

Comment: Don't edit it as solved. Instead, post what you did (or consider to be the solution, even if it's buying a new motherboard) as an answer, and mark it as an Answer two days later. That way, this question doesn't get bumped for being unanswered / unaccepted. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After failing to avoid freezing by SW settings, I resorted to last resort: Baking motherboard. :)
Result: Device is bricked. It wont even start. I will buy a new motherboard.